# Accessing getter from another class

Tags: c#, class, getter

Hey I have two classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BMIcalculator
{
    class BmrCalculator
    {
        BMIcalculator BMICalc = new BMIcalculator();
        
        private int age;
        private double BMR;
        private Gender Gender; 
        private double weight;
        private double height;

        public void setWeight(double weight)
        {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public void setHeight(double height)
        {
            this.height = height;
        }

        public double GetWeight()
        {
            return weight;
        }
        public double GetHeight()
        {
            return height;
        }

        public void SetGender(Gender Gender)
        {
            this.Gender = Gender;
        }
        public Gender GetGender()
        {
            return this.Gender;
        }

        public double CalculateBMR()
        {
            
            if (Gender == Gender.Female)
            {
                BMR = (10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) - 161;
            }
            else
            {
                BMR = (10 * BMICalc.getWeight()) + (6.25 * BMICalc.getHeight()) - (5 * age) + 5;
            }
            return BMR;
        }
        public void SetAge(int age)
        {
            this.age = age;
        }

    }
}
```

2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BMIcalculator
{
     class BMIcalculator
    {
        private double height;
        private double weight;
        private UnitTypes unit;

        public BMIcalculator()
        {
            unit = UnitTypes.Metric;
        }

        #region Setters and getters
        public double getHeight()
        {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(double height)
        {
            if(height >= 0.0)
            this.height = height;
        }

        public double getWeight()
        {
            return weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(double weight)
        {
            if (weight >= 0.0)
                this.weight = weight;
        }

        public UnitTypes getUnit()
        {
            return unit;
        }

        public void setUnit(UnitTypes unit)
        {
            this.unit = unit;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Main form:

```
namespace BMIcalculator
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private string name = string.Empty; // instance variable
        BMIcalculator bmiCalc = new BMIcalculator();
        BmrCalculator bmrCalc = new BmrCalculator();

        public MainForm()
        {      
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeGUI();
            
        }

        private void InitializeGUI()
        {
            rbtnMetric.Checked = true;
            lblBmr.Text = String.Empty;
        }
        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CenterToScreen();
        }
        #region BMICalculator
        private void UpdateHeightText()
        {
            if(rbtnMetric.Checked == true)
            {
                lblHeight.Text = "Height (Cm)";
                lblWeight.Text = "Weight (Kg)";

            }
            else
            {
                lblHeight.Text = "Height (Ft)";
                lblWeight.Text = "Weight (lbs)";
            }

        }
        

        private void rbtnMetric_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateHeightText();
            
        }

        private void rbtnImperial_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateHeightText();
            
        }


        private bool ReadInputBMI()
        {
            ReadUnit();
            bool weightOK = ReadWeight();
            bool heightOK = ReadHeight();
            

            return weightOK && heightOK;
        }
        
        private void ReadUnit() // this void looks which one is checked
        {
            if(rbtnMetric.Checked)
            {
                bmiCalc.setUnit(UnitTypes.Metric);
            }
            else
            {
                bmiCalc.setUnit(UnitTypes.Imperial);
            }
        }

        private bool ReadWeight()
        {
            double weight = 0.0;
            bool ok = double.TryParse(txtWeight.Text, out weight);
            if (!ok)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid weight value , error");
            }
            bmiCalc.setWeight(weight);
            return ok;
        }

        private bool ReadHeight()
        {
            double height = 0.0;
            bool ok = double.TryParse(txtCmFt.Text, out height);
            if (!ok)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid height value , error");
            }

            double inch = 0.0;
            // cm -> m ft -> inches
            if(bmiCalc.getUnit() == UnitTypes.Metric)
            {
                height = height / 100; // cm -> m
            }
            else 
            {
                height = height * 12.0 + inch; // ft -> inch
            }

            bmiCalc.setHeight(height);
            return ok;
        }

        #endregion

        #region BMRCalculator
        private void UpdateGenderStatus()
        {
            if(rbtnFemale.Checked)
            {
                bmrCalc.SetGender(Gender.Female);
            }
            else
            {
                bmrCalc.SetGender(Gender.Male);
            }
        }
        private void rbtnFemale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateGenderStatus();
        }

        private void rbtnMale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateGenderStatus();
        }

        private void ReadAge()
        {
            int age;
            bool ok = int.TryParse(txtAge.Text , out age);

            if(!ok)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Wrong Age");
            }
            else
            {
                bmrCalc.SetAge(age);
            }
        }
        #endregion


        private void btnCalculateBMR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            double weight = double.Parse(txtWeight.Text);
            double height = double.Parse(txtCmFt.Text);

            bmrCalc.setWeight(weight);
            bmrCalc.setHeight(height);
            ReadAge();
            //bmrCalc.CalculateBMR();
            lblBmr.Text = bmrCalc.CalculateBMR().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

designer:

```
      namespace BMIcalculator
{
    partial class MainForm
    {
    /// <summary>
    ///  Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    ///  Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.lblHeight = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.txtCmFt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.rbtnMetric = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
        this.lblWeight = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.txtWeight = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.groupBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.btnCalculateBMR = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox6 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.lblBmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.txtAge = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblAge = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.groupBox5 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.rbtnMale = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
        this.rbtnFemale = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
        this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupBox4.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupBox6.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupBox5.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // lblHeight
        // 
        this.lblHeight.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblHeight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(27, 39);
        this.lblHeight.Name = "lblHeight";
        this.lblHeight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(54, 20);
        this.lblHeight.TabIndex = 1;
        this.lblHeight.Text = "Height";
        // 
        // txtCmFt
        // 
        this.txtCmFt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(165, 32);
        this.txtCmFt.Name = "txtCmFt";
        this.txtCmFt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(51, 27);
        this.txtCmFt.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.rbtnMetric);
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(319, 23);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(163, 88);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 6;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "Unit";
        // 
        // rbtnMetric
        // 
        this.rbtnMetric.AutoSize = true;
        this.rbtnMetric.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(26, 35);
        this.rbtnMetric.Name = "rbtnMetric";
        this.rbtnMetric.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 24);
        this.rbtnMetric.TabIndex = 0;
        this.rbtnMetric.TabStop = true;
        this.rbtnMetric.Text = "Metric(kg,cm)";
        this.rbtnMetric.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.rbtnMetric.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rbtnMetric_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // lblWeight
        // 
        this.lblWeight.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblWeight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(27, 77);
        this.lblWeight.Name = "lblWeight";
        this.lblWeight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 20);
        this.lblWeight.TabIndex = 9;
        this.lblWeight.Text = "Weight";
        // 
        // txtWeight
        // 
        this.txtWeight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(165, 70);
        this.txtWeight.Name = "txtWeight";
        this.txtWeight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 27);
        this.txtWeight.TabIndex = 10;
        // 
        // groupBox4
        // 
        this.groupBox4.Controls.Add(this.btnCalculateBMR);
        this.groupBox4.Controls.Add(this.groupBox6);
        this.groupBox4.Controls.Add(this.txtAge);
        this.groupBox4.Controls.Add(this.lblAge);
        this.groupBox4.Controls.Add(this.groupBox5);
        this.groupBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(27, 130);
        this.groupBox4.Name = "groupBox4";
        this.groupBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(392, 314);
        this.groupBox4.TabIndex = 15;
        this.groupBox4.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox4.Text = "BMR calculator";
        // 
        // btnCalculateBMR
        // 
        this.btnCalculateBMR.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(68, 274);
        this.btnCalculateBMR.Name = "btnCalculateBMR";
        this.btnCalculateBMR.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(212, 29);
        this.btnCalculateBMR.TabIndex = 4;
        this.btnCalculateBMR.Text = "Calculate BMR";
        this.btnCalculateBMR.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnCalculateBMR.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnCalculateBMR_Click);
        // 
        // groupBox6
        // 
        this.groupBox6.Controls.Add(this.lblBmr);
        this.groupBox6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(177, 55);
        this.groupBox6.Name = "groupBox6";
        this.groupBox6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(185, 213);
        this.groupBox6.TabIndex = 3;
        this.groupBox6.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox6.Text = "how many calories you need";
        // 
        // lblBmr
        // 
        this.lblBmr.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblBmr.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 67);
        this.lblBmr.Name = "lblBmr";
        this.lblBmr.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 20);
        this.lblBmr.TabIndex = 5;
        this.lblBmr.Text = "label10";
        // 
        // txtAge
        // 
        this.txtAge.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(98, 182);
        this.txtAge.Name = "txtAge";
        this.txtAge.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 27);
        this.txtAge.TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // lblAge
        // 
        this.lblAge.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblAge.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 185);
        this.lblAge.Name = "lblAge";
        this.lblAge.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(36, 20);
        this.lblAge.TabIndex = 1;
        this.lblAge.Text = "Age";
        // 
        // groupBox5
        // 
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add(this.rbtnMale);
        this.groupBox5.Controls.Add(this.rbtnFemale);
        this.groupBox5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 42);
        this.groupBox5.Name = "groupBox5";
        this.groupBox5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(131, 125);
        this.groupBox5.TabIndex = 0;
        this.groupBox5.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox5.Text = "Gender";
        // 
        // rbtnMale
        // 
        this.rbtnMale.AutoSize = true;
        this.rbtnMale.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 63);
        this.rbtnMale.Name = "rbtnMale";
        this.rbtnMale.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(63, 24);
        this.rbtnMale.TabIndex = 1;
        this.rbtnMale.TabStop = true;
        this.rbtnMale.Text = "Male";
        this.rbtnMale.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.rbtnMale.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rbtnMale_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // rbtnFemale
        // 
        this.rbtnFemale.AutoSize = true;
        this.rbtnFemale.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 33);
        this.rbtnFemale.Name = "rbtnFemale";
        this.rbtnFemale.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(78, 24);
        this.rbtnFemale.TabIndex = 0;
        this.rbtnFemale.TabStop = true;
        this.rbtnFemale.Text = "Female";
        this.rbtnFemale.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.rbtnFemale.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rbtnFemale_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 20F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(512, 484);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.txtWeight);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblWeight);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.txtCmFt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblHeight);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainForm_Load);
        this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox4.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox4.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox6.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox6.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox5.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox5.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion
    private Label lblHeight;
    private TextBox txtCmFt;
    private GroupBox groupBox1;
    private RadioButton rbtnMetric;
    private Label lblWeight;
    private TextBox txtWeight;
    private GroupBox groupBox4;
    private Button btnCalculateBMR;
    private GroupBox groupBox6;
    private TextBox txtAge;
    private Label lblAge;
    private GroupBox groupBox5;
    private RadioButton rbtnMale;
    private RadioButton rbtnFemale;
    private Label lblBmr;
    }
}
```

The problem is i cant acess another class by creating **new BMIcalculator();** because then its empty or 0.
So my question is how can i access the getter from the BMIcalculator without creating new object. I want to get access to instance variables height and weigh and then use it in Bmrcalculator.

I have very similar problem to this one: [Call Methods from another class c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653649/call-methods-from-another-class-c-sharp)
but i still cant solve it. I began programming 2 weeks ago, sorry if its an obvious question.

Comment: Just because you name a method `get`Something doesn't make it a getter. There is specific syntax for getters and setters: ` public double Height { get { return this.height; } }` or in later versions of C#, `public double Height => this.height;`. I suggest reading a tutorial on basic C# before asking here though.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and your programming journey. "how can i access the getter from the BMIcalculator without creating new object" unless the method is static, you need an object instance, but that wouldn't really make sense here. How do you want the height and weight to get assigned? User input?

Comment: @luke acess is by forms i have whole code written 400 lines but i just posted here little part. User inputs value to text box.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile - `BMR` and `Gender` are never declared.

Comment: @Dai sorry do i have to post whole code? Those two classes are quite big.

Comment: A [mre] is what we're looking for. As mentioned on [ask], which is a good place to bookmark for tips on writing good questions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I will look in this, thank you so much btw i wasn't expecting such a fast answer.

Comment: You are correct, the problem is having two lines `bmiCalc = new BMICalculator();`, one in the BMRCalculator and one in the form.  Create it in one place and pass it to the other that also needs it.

Comment: @BenVoig How can i pass it from mainform?

Comment: By added it as a argument to `BmrCalculator` constructor and saving it as `this.BMICalc = passedInCalculator;` So your main form would look like `BmrCalculator bmrCalc = new BmrCalculator(bmiCalc);`